# Get "jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ','" error when exececute PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I wrote some java code to insert data into SQL Server 2012's Database when the user presses a button. When I run the code, I get this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ','.

and it says that the `sqlstatement.executeUpdate();` line caused the error. I know that this line is not a problem. The problem is my sql query but I cannot find how my query is wrong. Would you please help me?

Here the code

```
count++;
for(int count = 0; count < table_1.getRowCount(); count++){
    try { Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
          Connection dbconbt8 = DriverManager.getConnection("" +"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Store;user=sa;password=XXXXXX");
          String sqlQ = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transaction]([TransactionID],[ProductID]"+
           ",[TotalPrice]) VALUES ("+count+"','"+table_1.getValueAt(count, 0).toString()+"','"+sumprice+ "') ";
           PreparedStatement sqlstatement = dbconbt8.prepareStatement(sqlQ);
           sqlstatement.executeUpdate();
                       sqlstatement.close();
                       dbconbt8.close();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {

                          e1.printStackTrace();
                      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
```

Comment: Also go change your 'sa' password!

Comment: You ... really don't seem to understand the point of a PreparedStatement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing a single quote after `VALUES (` - this should fix the problem:

```
String sqlQ = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transaction]([TransactionID],[ProductID]"+
    ",[TotalPrice]) VALUES ('"+count+"','"+table_1.getValueAt(count, 0).toString()+"','"+sumprice+ "') ";
--                          ^
--                        Here
```

However, this is a bad fix: you should rewrite your query with parameters, so that the problem of quoting the data becomes irrelevant altogether:

```
String sqlQ = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transaction]([TransactionID],[ProductID],[TotalPrice]) VALUES (?,?,?) ";
PreparedStatement sqlstatement = dbconbt8.prepareStatement(sqlQ);
sqlstatement.setInt(1, count);
sqlstatement.setString(2, table_1.getValueAt(count, 0).toString());
sqlstatement.setInt(3, sumprice);
sqlstatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: So it was (almost) valid T-SQL?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Apart from being open to SQL injection attacks, yes. T-SQL uses square brackets as "quotation marks" for names.